# How to execute commands on a 3rd party app using adb commands or something similar

Tags: android, testing, apk, adb

I have a use case which requires an app, not developed by me, to be controlled. I have adb access to the android device. These are the steps that are required to be performed:

1. Input text in two fields
2. Press Enter
3. Select checkboxes
4. Enter text into another text field
5. Enter

I know I can use `adb input keyevent <event-code>` and `adb input touchpad tap <x> <y>`, but these are brutish methods that won't work every time. I have looked into appium, but it seems to be limited to mobile web applications. Other frameworks like Espresso work, if you've built the app yourself.

I could not find any good answer to this problem. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: your question seems quite broad (too broad) at the moment. i think you should change your title : `how to execute commands on a 3rd party app using adb commands` or something similar to that, so that it focuses on adb _specifically_. just a suggestion :)

Comment: otherwise you're basically asking for suggestions on frameworks or software, and that is off-topic

Comment: @a_local_nobody Okkay

Comment: it's just a suggestion though, but i think you _might_ have more luck finding answers to using adb specifically

Comment: Hey I need the answer, better to ask a question that attracts more people :D

Comment: yeah i understand your frustration, but this might be your best bet at getting _any_ answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator).
It will enable you to launch a third-party app and perform any actions you want with it. In order to examine the UI and create the right locators, there's a command-line tool called uiautomatorviewer, bundled along with Android SDK.

Comment: `error while obtaining ui hierarchy XML file:java.io.IOException:EOF`

Comment: I think UIAutomator is deprecated. It doesn't work when I open the `.bat` file

Comment: UIAutomator is an Android library. Take a look at [the code sample](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/blob/master/ui/uiautomator/BasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/uiautomator/BasicSample/ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java) on how to launch an app and perform a simple action

Comment: I have asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337426/uiautomatorviewer-not-capturing-screenshot-at-all).