# UiAutomatorViewer Not capturing screenshot at all

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have come from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63296171/5345646) answer which suggests the usage of [Ui Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator), which requires the tool `UiAutomatorViewer` to be used.

The tool itself can be found at:
`<android-sdk>/tools/bin`

When I open it I get:
[image]

And when I try a screen shot, I get:

[image]

How do I deal with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so actually my PC didn't have the read permission for smartphones (office). After getting the permission the tool worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is seen when your device is currently busy with some kind of debug mode from IDE or another screen sharing app like vysor is already active

You can also try to reboot the device and try UiAutomatorViewer again without opening anyother IDE/app

Comment: Okay I will try this, and  will update you with the results